# adding preference pane to an application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nspreferencepane

I have an application which resides in menu bar, pretty much like this one
[image: menu app]

And I'm trying to create a preference pane for it, as described in [the apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/PreferencePanes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000110-SW1).
That guide shows how to create both prefpane plugin for System Preferences and preference window for standalone application. Yet, in the second case, it seems to be missing something.

So, I have main application class with `-(IBAction) displayPreferences:(id)sender;` action called when user clicks 'Preferences...' in the menu.
And I also have controller extending `NSPreferencePane` and connected to `NSWindow` object in Interface Builder (just likes docs describe).

The question is, how to connect them? I.e.,

```
-(IBAction) displayPreferences:(id)sender {
  // what do we write here to display preferences window?
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have System Preferences open to your preference pane, you can create a file URL to your `.prefPane` bundle and then send that to [`-[NSWorkspace openURL:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-BCIBBHIG).  If you want to be really explicit about launching options, you can use [`-[NSWorkspace openURLs:withAppBundleIdentifier:options:additionalEventParamDescriptor:launchIdentifiers:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-BCIJJBCG).

Comment: That's quite opposite, actually. [Apple says](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/Concepts/Application.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000702-CJBJFACH) that I can reuse PreferencePanes framework in my application, without adding anything to System Preferences. Is that correct?  (see 'Target Application' chapter in the link) Or should I just create new window and not bother with PreferencePanes framework?

Comment: @Nikita Yes that's correct.  The documentation (along with example code) on that is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/Tasks/OtherApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000711-BBCBAGAH).

Comment: Thanks, I must've missed item 1 there when reading before. I'll try it and see what happens! (gotta read about bundles too :/)

Comment: In particular, you should pass the “don't add to recents” option to the latter method. The user will not appreciate your prefpane showing up among their Recent Documents.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very simple way of opening preferences through apple script. Here you go.

1. You gotta create a button action and set the outlet of prefernces to the button action
2. And then, simply do the following apple script to open the main sys preference

   ```
   NSString *script = @"tell application \"System Preferences\"\n\tset the current pane to pane \"com.apple.preferences\"\n\tactivate\nend tell";


   NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:script];
   [appleScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
   ```

the script object can be modified according to where the user has to be navigated. be it bluetooth settings or wifi settings.